# how to work in symfony with database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am new to symfony framwork, i'm using symfony1.4.20 by my teacher recommend, the problem now is, i can't query it to my database. Can anyone help me in pointing the problem??

This is the code present in my actions class,

```
class contentActions extends sfActions
{
     public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
     {
         $this->forward('default', 'module');
     }
     public function executeGetuser(){
         $this->user_list = Doctrine::getTable('user')
                ->createQuery('u')
                ->execute();

         foreach($this->user_list as $row) {
                $id = $row->id;               
                $name = $row->name;           
         }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error as follows,

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Exception
Couldn't find class user
stack trace

at ()
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Table.php line 299 ...
            {
                $name = $this->_options['name'];
                if ( ! class_exists($name) || empty($name)) {
                    throw new Doctrine_Exception("Couldn't find class " . $name);
                }
                $record = new $name($this);
at Doctrine_Table->initDefinition()
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Table.php line 256 ...
at Doctrine_Table->__construct('user', object('Doctrine_Connection_Mysql'), 1)
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php line 1126 ...
at Doctrine_Connection->getTable('user')
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Core.php line 1090 ...
at Doctrine_Core::getTable('user')
in SF_ROOT_DIR\apps\userlogin\modules\content\actions\actions.class.php line 32 ...
at contentActions->executeGetuser(object('sfWebRequest'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\action\sfActions.class.php line 60 ...
at sfActions->execute(object('sfWebRequest'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\filter\sfExecutionFilter.class.php line 92 ...
at sfExecutionFilter->executeAction(object('contentActions'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\filter\sfExecutionFilter.class.php line 78 ...
at sfExecutionFilter->handleAction(object('sfFilterChain'), object('contentActions'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\filter\sfExecutionFilter.class.php line 42 ...
at sfExecutionFilter->execute(object('sfFilterChain'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php line 53 ...
at sfFilterChain->execute()
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\filter\sfRenderingFilter.class.php line 33 ...
at sfRenderingFilter->execute(object('sfFilterChain'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php line 53 ...
at sfFilterChain->execute()
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\controller\sfController.class.php line 238 ...
at sfController->forward('content', 'getuser')
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\controller\sfFrontWebController.class.php line 48 ...
at sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\util\sfContext.class.php line 170 ...
at sfContext->dispatch()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\web\userlogin_dev.php line 13 ...
```

Can anyone help me in the process of fixing this error and make the code work in symfony with database ?

Comment: As the exception you have not created the file .... at the path lib/mnodel/doctrine/UserTable.class.php check is it exist.

Comment: If you're *new* to Symfony, why use an ancient version? ~ [*"As of November 2012, symfony 1.x is not maintained anymore and you are encouraged to have a look at Symfony2 for any new projects."*](http://symfony.com/legacy)

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ so what should i do ? yes i don't have it yet ..

Comment: @Phil is as my teacher recommend, could u help with any guide  ??

Comment: There's a pretty good guide right here - http://symfony.com/get-started

Comment: check the symfony site else create that file.

Comment: @mulrali - did you build the model classes for your project? (`./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`) If you did check how did you name your `user` entity exactly (the names are case sensitive so `User` != `user`).

Comment: Thank @MichalTrojanowski I am follow by this http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/03?orm=Propel  now i got it. thank all help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->user_list = Doctrine::getTable('User')
```

With uppercase U